# Setting a cell value based on a SUMIF function

Tags: excel

I have a sheet of cargo items to stack on rolltrailers. In general, which type of rolltrailer they get loaded onto depends on their length, but for the smallest size (bolsters) I want to move the cargo up to the next larger model of rolltrailer once a certain weight capacity is reached. Essentially, I want:

***IF*** Total Weight of All cargo under length limit > 4 x Bolster capacity **THEN** RT="40RT" **ELSE** RT="Bolster"

I have quantities in col **E**, lengths in col **F**, weight in col **I**, total weights (qty x weight) in col **J**, and selected rolltrailer in col **M**. The maximum number of bolsters is stored in the `BolsterCutoff` reference.

I've tried using this:

```
=IF(SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,3,FALSE)>$F2, $J$2:$J$501)/1000>BolsterCutoff*VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,6,FALSE),"40RT","Bolster")
```

...but it doesn't seem to work - it doesn't sum anything at all.

Now, what I *hoped* that would do is use `SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,3,FALSE)>$F2, $J$2:$J$501)` to sum up the total weight in metric tonnes where the length (col F) is less than or equal to the maximum length allowed on bolsters (`VLOOKUP("Bolster", RT_Details, 3, FALSE)`).

I'm pretty certain the problem lies in my `SUMIF` function - I've boiled it down to:

```
=SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, F2 & "<=10", $J$2:$J$501)
```

...and it still shows zero. I've tried switching columns F and J around just in case I've been confused all along, and still no luck.

Can anyone help? I'm stumped.

**EDIT:** I've just tried `=SUMIF(E2:E16, "<50", J2:J16)` and that works fine.
I've also tried removing the cell reference and using the VLOOKUP both inside the condition and broken out:

```
SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, "<=VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,6,FALSE)", $I$2:$I$501)

SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, "<=" & VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,6,FALSE), $I$2:$I$501)
```

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to John Bustos I got the actual `SUMIF` working (I'd called the wrong column index in the VLOOKUP), but it still doesn't seem to be producing the right numbers. Here's the complete code in context:

```
 IF(SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, "<=" & VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,3,FALSE), $J$2:$J$501)/1000>BolsterCutoff*VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,6,FALSE),"40RT","Bolster")
```

GOAL: Sum all the total weights (in `$J$2:$J$501`) where the length (in `$F$2:$F$501`) is equal to or less than the maximum cargo length (`VLOOKUP("Bolster", RT_Details, 3, FALSE)`) for the bolster. That is then divided by `1000` to give the total weight in metric tonnes, and compared to the maximum number of bolsters per quote (`BolsterCutoff`) multiplied by the maximum load capacity (`VLOOKUP("Bolster", RT_Details, 6, FALSE)`). If the total load of all the bolster-sized cargo is more than `BolsterCutoff * [Max load]`, it returns `40RT`, otherwise it returns `Bolster`.

I'm missing something obvious, and I can feel the shape of it drifting right at the edge of my mind, but I just can't pin it down...

Comment: I'm slightly confused - This statement: `F2 & "<=10"` doesn't make sense to me (and not to excel either) - What are you trying to do there?
Your last function - `SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, "<=" & VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,6,FALSE), $I$2:$I$501)` should at least start returning values....

Comment: Well, the VLOOKUP returns the max cargo length for the bolster, which is 10 metres; I'm trying to make it count the total weight of cargo items with a length less than or equal to 10m. I tried using just `"<=10"`, and that works fine, but as soon as I put a lookup in it returns errors.

Comment: Actually, could it be due to the quotation marks in `"Bolster"`? I'll try using `Char(34)` instead ...

Comment: Got to this, which seems to be working. I'd put the wrong column index in the vlookup.  `=SUMIF($F$2:$F$501, "<=" & VLOOKUP("Bolster",RT_Details,3,FALSE), $J$2:$J$501)`

Comment: So all's working now?

Comment: Most irksome - it's working on its own, but still doesn't return the right size. I'll put a new example in the question.

Comment: Found it. I'd switched to summing the total weights, without remembering that that column was already in tonnes - so the calculation was dividing it way too far. Thanks, @JohnBustos, without your confirmation that the code was right I'd never even have thought to look at the basic calculation.

Comment: Glad you got it working, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: when summing a column in kilogrammes that is converted to metric tonnes by dividing by a thousand, remember to remove that division when you switch to summing a column that's already in metric tonnes.

Unit confusion. Well, that was a simple fix once I spotted it. :-D